# Check if there is any mail in an outlook folder received yesterday

Tags: python, email, outlook, pywin32, win32com

I need to check and verify if there is any mail received in a specific outlook folder on the day before using python code.

I am able to access folder and read mails. But somehow, latest mail is not read when I tried GetLast() method. I use win32com module and Outlook MAPI object to do this.

Is there any way to check if there are mails received on yesterday?

Comment: Show us your code and explain when it does not work.

Comment: It is reading all mails. Just that, GetLast() is not getting the latest mail. This confused me. I tried displaying all dates in loop and found the latest mail displayed last. So its ok

Comment: Items collection is not sorted in any particular way until you call Sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Items.Restrict`:

```
yesterdaysItems = MAPIFolder.Items.Restrict("@SQL=(ReceivedTime < '7/21/2016') AND (ReceivedTime > '7/20/2016') ")
```